# Anybody ever had a clingy friend?

Tags: outdoor-games

I have a workmate and I've known her for about 7 months already. She is very touchy with me recently and I'm really confused with her because we are both girls and she presently have a boyfriend. It all started when she invited me for a dinner at restaurant and had some talks. We both enjoyed it and she again invited me during the next week until we've been doing this during our day offs. We've been hanging outside together, eating at restaurants, and we usually pull over the car and had simple conversations about everything. When we got home she calls me until we fell asleep. She consistently sends me message every day about work and random stuffs. I am just very very confuse until recently why is she so touchy with me. Once, when we were both at work, she grabbed my hand and seems she wanted to hold my hands secretly while our coworkers aren't aware. Also, while I am driving she usually touches (rubs) my arms while we are talking. Sometimes, she would hold my hand while it was on the gearshift. Most of the time, she puts her arms behind my head while I am driving. But we are talking so I just don't mind it. Another thing, when our hands get closer, she would anchor it with her pinky finger. And just recently, we ordered food and had to wait outside. We just talked inside the car random topics while she was rubbing (playing) her hands with mine and she just grabbed it like a real holding hands. She also laid her head on my shoulder and hugged me.At first I didn't mind this thinking she is just really touchy with everyone. By the way, she is a very nice and funny person. I just want to know what's going on. She rarely talks about her boyfriend. But knowing their relationship, I know they are having a rough time because she had some issues with her boyfriend. But I also know that she really loves her boyfriend. It's just her boyfriend doesn't want to go out with her on public places because he's "uncomfortable" with crowd as she told me. During our hangouts, she never told her boyfriend that we were eating outside or we were somewhere together. Anybody here tried this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be on-topic at all here.  It might be on topic at interpersonal skills, with a bit of copy-editing.

Comment: But srsly tho, please do some editing before posting on another site. This is a giant wall of text with poor punctuation and runon sentences.